# having access to elements in another layout

Tags: android, layout

In my application I have an expandablelistview in which I use a layout to show the items of list view.
Now I want to change the color of the textview in that layout but I dont know who to do it.

```
View view = View.inflate(getBaseContext(),R.layout.parent_layout, null);

    TextView parent_txt  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
   parent_txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: If you could post your Java code and both of your layouts that would be very helpful

Comment: Do you mean the background?

Comment: No I want to change the color of the textveiw on that layout

Comment: This code would work for your purposes. Is it in the right place? What class is it in and what class is the R.layout.parent_layout used in?

Comment: my code is in main activity and when I trace the code the debuger run it but do not make any changes. parent layout is used to show items of listveiw

Comment: Do you start the activity that uses parent_layout after the above code is run?

Comment: yes I do.   exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
  Movies_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
  Movies_list = new ArrayList<String>(Movies_category.keySet());
  adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, Movies_category, Movies_list);
  exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that you are altering the color of your `TextView` before the view has been created since the layout is from another `Activity` that wasn't started yet.

First, create an `Intent` to transition to your other activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("textColor", "#000000")
startActivity(i);
```

Next, in your `SecondActivity`'s onCreate, get the color:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String textColor = bundle.getString("textColor");
//update the text
TextView parent_txt  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
parent_txt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));
```

This should work since the layout is now created since the code is run in the same activity that uses the `R.layout.parent_txt` activity layout.

Comment: There is no activity connected to the parent_layout and it is used to show the elements of listview